# spring boot test slices for Web applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have an `SpringBootApplication` annotated class that also extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to provider websecurity. This application also has a JPA layer which I want to test in isolation.

The appliation class roughly looks like

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

Now I have a repository test that looks roughly like

```
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@DatabaseSetup(Stubs.MASTER_DATASET)
public class AppUserRepositoryTest {
...
}
```

However when I run this I get an error that says an ObjectPostProcessor needs to be wired. While I can understand the reason, Trying to understand if there is any workaround/solution to avoid having to define `@MockBeans` for all of the dependencies in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. The error I get is

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method setObjectPostProcessor in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Can you consider moving your configuration to another class under application class and leave application class with only main method and @SpringBootConfiguration. As DataJpatest needs this kind of project setup

Comment: Am Sorry, Didn't quite follow. Do you mean Changing my main Application class to not extend WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter ? And then having another @Configuration annotated class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapterInstead ?

Comment: Exactly as you mentioned

Comment: I had already had a test setup with profiles to have JpaOnlyApplication, WebOnlyApplication etc., that disabled autoconfiguration of others. Feels for sliced tests will just have to change the annotations on them.

Comment: Perhaps my point is from spring boot issues https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7999 recommendations. It has some points

Comment: Did this recommendation solved your issue?